# How do I really deploy docker-compose.yml to the cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, deployment, docker-compose, cloud

I have a `docker-compose.yml` configuratio that spin up multiple services such as `SQL Server`, `redis` and `Elasticsearch`. Everything is fine in the local development, I run `docker-compose up -d --build` on a Windows machine and exposes its `IP` and `ports` number to the public. That's how I deploy my docker containers.

But how do I deploy it to the cloud? What website offers this service? I know `AWS` could host containers but could it run `docker-compose up -d --build`?

I have been trying to google search `deploy docker containers` but all I could find was to deploy the docker containers on your local machine, or use `kubernetes` to deploy which I have no understanding about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking `docker-compose` can be used to deploy in a production environment. Only one difference that you can do, instead of build the image you can push the images to [AWS ECR](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/) or any alternative registry like Gitlab registry if you are using Gitlab then you can pull the image directly to the server/instance where you are going to deploy.

Also AWS has a service called [ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) which also can be used to deploy containers but without using `docker-compose`

Comment: If the images from `docker-compose.yml` are already being pulled from the cloud I don't have to do this right? How about the ports? Would ports from different services be exposed as normal? Let's say http://example.com. Elasticseach with be on http://example.com:9200 and Nodejs on http://example.com:3000?

Comment: yes if they are public images already then no need to host them yourself. regarding the ports it will be the same no difference just make sure to allow the needed ports in your security group if you need them to be exposed publicly and to specific ips. for example port 80 will be public , ssh port (the host itself) should be for specific ips and so on. elastic search no need to expose it as long as it will used internally only same goes to nodejs you need to have a reverse proxy in front of it. you might use nginx container for this case

Comment: @PineAppleBanana if you need further explanation please let me know and if this answer works for you please consider marking it as accepted answer for your question.

Comment: Docker now has ECS integration
https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-integration/

Answer (score 5):

I have an example here in my github repo of spinning up docker compose on Amazon Lightsail, but the process would be very similar for EC2

Scroll down to the Docker part of the readme. For EC2 instead of using the "launch script" dialogue you just paste the script into the user data section in the EC2 creation process.

https://github.com/mikegcoleman/todo